# sprite not showing pygame and tuple no attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I've been working on this issue for a week. Researched through here and other sources... still can't solve it. The surface is displayed, but the sprite is not showing up.

Code is:

```
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame

class teemoShows(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, position):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        teemoFile = "teemoX.png"
        self.image = pygame.image.load(teemoFile).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = position[0]
        self.rect.y = position[1]

    def update(self):
        #update sprites .. is this correct?
        #self.rect = self.rect.move([0, yposition - self.rect.y])
        pygame.update(self)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))
character = teemoShows([screen.get_rect().x, screen.get_rect().y])

# create sprite group and add character
teemoFile = pygame.sprite.Group()
teemoFile.add(character)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           sys.exit()
           # main loop
    pygame.display.flip()
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    teemoFile.draw(screen)
    teemoFile.update()
```

The error it gives me is:

```
line 31, in <module>
  character = teemoShows([screen.get_rect().x, screen.get_rect().y])
  File "C:\Python27\arminProject_two\textBased_adv.py", line 21, in __init__
  self.rect.x = position[0]
NameError: module object has no attribute 'update.'
```

Comment: please set intendation

Comment: Then become familiar with [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) and [`pygame`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/).

Comment: wow I received a -1 because of that....what a great community we have here. The intendation is correct.

Comment: In your code "character" is a tuple and not a rectangle object. If you want to use update() and draw() methods you should use a rectangle object. The method get_rect(**kwargs) return a new rectangle, is this what you wish to use?

Comment: Can I pass the image as a rectangle object and be able to use the method get_rect() ?

Comment: If that is your indentation, it probably shouldn't be - why would you run that code when the class is defined? Also, why do you never create a `teemoShows` instance?

Comment: try character = screen.get_rect()

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: I will make the changes once I'm home to test it out.
It's supposed to display a window and the sprite. Once I learn that going to build a 2D game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the line `character = screen.get_rect().x, screen.get_rect().y` is assigning the variable `character` to a tuple, when you are actually trying to make it an instance of the `teemoShows` class that is why you are getting the error because the tuple doesnt have an update method

here is the proper way:

```
character = teemoShows([screen.get_rect().x, screen.get_rect().y])

#In your main-loop 
character.update()
character.draw(screen)
```

this way you are making a `teemoShows` instance and supplying the tuple as a parameter for `position`

Comment: where should I put the  character.update() and .draw(screen) ? Is the main loop the same place as character = teemoShows([]) place?

Comment: in the loop, becuase you want to re-draw the sprite each loop, also the, you generally override the update method to move the sprite how you please

Comment: Added the changes and now it says 'teemoShows' is not defined aw men lol.

Comment: in your posted code there is code in the teemoShows class that shouldnt be indented

Comment: Which code? I can try indenting and not-indenting pieces of code to see where the error lies, but if you see it. It would be faster to point out.

Comment: @ProHacks123 put the draw and update *in* the main loop

Comment: Does that look better? Even if that is the case... I'm still not seeing the Sprite... never knew how much of a pain sprites were.

Comment: its not a pain if you know *anything* about pygame, here https://gist.github.com/C-Dubb/33d4e9fd0f16e8f447b3

Comment: Okay I implemented the revisions you have suggested. Updated the code. The new error is: "global position is not defined." I'm sure there are some errors in the code if you could please take a look. Thank you!

Comment: I did and now the new error is: 'global yposition is not defined.' So I removed the whole line under 'def update(self):' new error is: 'module object has no attribute update.' I added: 'self' to pygame.update(self)' same error persists.... I quit. I go from error to error infinite amount of times.

Comment: some advice: Learn python before you try pygame

Comment: Agreed. I thought pygame wasn't a challenging module even for a novice Python user. I'm currently using 'Learn Python the Hard Way.' Most of it is a review... haven't reached the confusing parts yet. Thanks though for all of your help!

Comment: @ProHacks123 Keep at it! you will get there eventually

Comment: Will do! I added your github acc for future references... and questions lol.